# How can I uninstall Microsoft Paint 3D on Windows 10 Version 1703 (Build 15063.674)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, powershell, windows-10-v1703, paint-3d-preview

I am trying to remove Paint 3D from Windows 10.

I have tried to following commands in a Powershell executed as an Administrator:

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.MSPaint | Remove-AppxPackage
```

as well as

```
Get-AppxPackage *mspaint* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

For a moment it seems to work, and Paint 3D is gone, but then it gets magically reinstalled.

Please advise.

Comment: Remove provisioned package with `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage` command. Use full package name after it.

Comment: @Biswa why not make that an answer? It is, in fact, the answer.

Comment: @Appleoddity I do not know if it works for OP. So just trial-error.

Comment: Wow, that really seems to work so far...

Comment: Of course it is broken in the new Fall Creators Update Version 1709